# Build sphinx4 using eclipse

Tags: sphinx4

I have been trying to build sphinx4 in eclipse for a long time with no success!

I import all the sphinx sources and add all the necessary external Jar files, but
eclipse doesn't recognize most of the packages therefore I can't build it.

Many Thanks,

Iman

Answer (score 0):

First of all You checkout the latest version of Sphinx4 through this command(this is the main step as everyday code gets committed as Errors Get discovered)

> svn co
>   https://cmusphinx.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cmusphinxtrunk/sphinx4
>   sphinx4

Then Go to the Following Link to know wot to do further

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/

And then if still you are not able to run it then Explain your errors in detail,So that i can help you further..:)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Iman,
Go to following link. It will be helpfull for you...:)

http://puneetk.com/sphinx-4-0-video-tutorial-high-quality